# IIS deployment cold query

Tags: .net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, iis-8

Deployed an .net core app but encountering the first request to be slow basically 2 seconds then on second and more request it is only less than a second.

I currently deployed pre compiled query, pre compiled model. I also set the IIS to have start mode always running idle time out to 0 and preload enabled to true. anyone encountered and resolved this would be a great help

Comment: Which runtime and version?

Comment: ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core is well known for such cold start delay (all tips you applied won't solve the delay for very first request). Use search engines and you can find decades of discussions on this topic. Live with it peacefully and the world is not ending.

Comment: This question is far too broad to answer conclusively.

Answer (score 0):

The startup time doesn't seem to be a single cause, it's the total time the process takes to start, load, network runtime, read configuration, load assemblies, etc. Your site is processing requests fast, unless it's in the cold start phase of the first request, or when it recycles or restarts. But delay for the first request is unavoidable.

What we can do is try our best to reduce unplanned restarts and recycles, but your app pool still recycles occasionally in production, and sometimes you must experience hangs, high CPU, memory leaks, or other issues with your website be recycled. So reset, restart, and recycle IIS the right way, and the cold boot time won't be a real problem.

**How to maximize IIS application pool availability:**

1. Install the application initialization module.

> To check if you have it installed:
>
> ```
> appcmd list config /section:globalModules | findstr warmup.dll
> ```

2. Start your application pool automatically without waiting for a request to start.

> Enable "AlwaysRunning" mode for your application pool
>
> ```
> appcmd set apppool TestApp /startMode:AlwaysRunning
> ```

3. Set up application initialization to warm up your application when the application pool starts.

> The " preloadEnabled " property needs to be used in the application
> definition, this will ensure that when the IIS worker process starts
> for our application pool, it will also initialize our application and
> trigger our preheat code.
>
> ```
>  appcmd set app "TestApp/" /preloadEnabled:true
> ```
>
> Then you need to make sure you have application initialization and
> warmup code in the Application_Start handler in global.asax. You also
> need to configure warmup for other parts of the application

4. Prevent your application pool from shutting down unexpectedly.

> Even with a startMode of "AlwaysRunning", IIS still honors the idle
> timeout setting. This causes your worker process to shut down after a
> period of inactivity. To prevent this, another application pool
> configuration change:
>
> ```
> appcmd set apppool "TestApp" /processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00
> ```

5. Set the optimal recycling policy for your application pool.

> Even though our application pool remains warm, there are still things
> that cause the application to restart, like changes to the application
> web.config.
>
> If you are making changes to a web application and want to minimize
> restarts, you can set:
>
> ```
> appcmd set config "TestApp" /section:httpRuntime /fcnMode:Disabled
> appcmd set config "TestApp" /section:compilation /numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart:1000
> ```
>
> This prevents the application from restarting on any changes except
> the root web.config.

I recommend you to read this [article](https://www.leansentry.com/guide/reset-restart-recycle-iis/max-application-pool-warmup#install-the-application-initialization-module) by **Mike Volodarsky**, you can get more useful information from it.